# Converting array into Generic List format?

Tags: c#, generics

I have come across some code that is exactly what I need for my program but it uses and array and I am unsure of how to convert it so it uses a generic list instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.Length; i++)
{
     if (people[i].DoThisAction(action, numberOfActions))  //starts with the first one, if cannot moves onto next one
        return true;
}
return false;
```

I want to be able to get a single "person" object from the list and use it in the if statement.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (amount of people in list); i++)
{
    if(people[indexnumberoflist].DoThisAction(action, numberofActions)) 
       return true; 
} 
return false;
```

Comment: Looks like the equivalent of a `.Any(...)` call.

Comment: what would the `people[i]` equivalent be?

Comment: If someone has a solution, please post it in a full 'question' response, so I get to give you the answer

Comment: Are you asking how to get objects out of a list (as opposed to an array)?

Comment: This code iterates over an array or list and returns true if DoThisAction returns true on the first return and false if nothing in the list returns true on DoThisAction. What specifically do you think it does?

Comment: Yes? I think so, I thought it was obvious looking at the code, I'm stuck on what the Generic List equivalent of `people[i].DoThisAction` would be

Comment: @wentimo it checks if a person can do the action, if not it returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you may be looking for is actually a foreach loop. It would look something like this:

```
foreach (var person in people)
{
    if(person.DoThisAction(action, numberofActions))
       return true;
}
return false;
```

Which can be further reduced to:

```
return people.Any(person => person.DoThisAction(action, numberofActions));
```

Using a LINQ-expression if you wish.